# Integrating Sine Wave shifted up by 1

Tags: matlab, simulink

When I integrate sine waves with 1Hz in Matlab, why does the result shift by 1? The integral block's initial value is 0. I would like to know why this happens and the correct way to solve it. The solution I came up with is to change the initial value to -1 and this solved the issue but I'm not sure about the consequences of changing the initial value. It seems Matlab assumes the integration constant is 2.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working with machines here! This one does not know the simplified paradigma(integral sin = -cos) we learn in maths! ;)

Simulink here just numerically integrates the sine. And it just starts from zero as you set. If you imagine the integration as area below the sine-curve, you can easily follow, what it does: The integral starts from zero and increases until x=pi, with a maximum slope where the sine is at its maximum (x=pi/2). Then, the sine changes to negative values, so the integral decreases again until it reaches 0 at x=2pi, where the two halfes of the sine just equalise. Just as to expect.

Or mathematically said:
The general antiderivative of `sin(x)` is `-cos(x) + A`. As the initial value of the integral is set to zero, you get the constraint of `-cos(0) + A = 0`, which comes to `A=1`. And `y = -cos(x) + 1` is just the blue curve you see.

Comment: what do you mean by 'integrate sine waves with 1Hz'? with 1/s you are integrating the input. If you multiply instead you differentiate. Review Laplace Transform basics, for instance here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform